# Creating a villager that will buy zombie pigman swords

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have made villagers before using [MC Stacker](http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com). Here is my dilemma: I want to have the villager buy a golden sword with *Looting II* on it and sell a written book. I have set that up but the villager will not seem to buy the sword; the NBT tags are different. The swords are not the same despite the enchantments being the same.

[image: Villager buys]
[image: Pigman dropped]

The villager will not trade since the NBT tags are different. How do I go about making them the same?

This is the command I used to summon the Villager:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Kunueme",CustomNameVisible:1,Profession:1,Career:0,CareerLevel:18,O‌​ffers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:golden_sword,Coun‌​t:1,tag:{ench:[{id:21,lvl:2}]}},sell:{id:written_book,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:‌​"A buck"},title:"",author:"The Street",generation:0,pages:["{text:\"\",color:black}"]}}}]}}
```

Comment: Can you provide all the relevant commands used, from creating the villager to obtaining the sword?

Comment: This is the command:
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Kunueme",CustomNameVisible:1,Profession:1,Career:0,CareerLevel:18,Offers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:golden_sword,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:21,lvl:2}]}},sell:{id:written_book,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"A buck"},title:"",author:"The Street",generation:0,pages:["{text:\"\",color:black}"]}}}]}}

Comment: The sword is a regular loot drop from a Pigman? Or is it some sort of special pigman?

Comment: Just a regular pigman drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your villager's `ench` tag contains `id` and `lvl` declared as Integers, while through normal means (enchanting, loot from pigmen) they would instead be Shorts. When matching NBT data, you must match even the datatypes. To declare a Short, you must append the numerical value with an "s".

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Kunueme",CustomNameVisible:1,Profession:1,Career:0,CareerLevel:18,Offers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:golden_sword,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:21s,lvl:2s}]}},sell:{id:written_book,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"A buck"},title:"",author:"The Street",generation:0,pages:["{text:\"\",color:black}"]}}}]}}
```

---

Something to keep in mind is that NBT matching for villager trades differs from NBT matching through various commands (such as `/scoreboard`). For commands, List tag matching (that which encases data in square brackets) is lenient, in that the data you look for is scanned throughout the entire target's list. However, villager trading itself uses strict List detection, in that the list you specify must match exactly as the target item has it specified.

For example, testing for `data:["a"]` on an entity that contains `data:["a","b"]` will work fine, since "a" appears somewhere within the target.

If a villager trade looks for `ench:[{id:21s,lvl:2s}]` on an item that contains `ench:[{id:21s,lvl:2s},{id:16s,lvl:1s}]`, it will **not** match because the lists are not exactly equal.

Villager trading is the only case as of 1.9 where List matching is strict. All other NBT matching will work fine. For example, if the item you're trading has a string tag that is not specified in the trade, the villager will still accept it and it will not conflict with trading.

Comment: This fixed it, However if the order of the enchantments is not the same as the vendors the villager will not buy it. I will just have to set all the orders for each set of enchants to be able to buy each sword. That's going to be a heck of a list ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a tag on the sword in your inventory that's not on the sword the villager wants. Try throwing your sword on the ground and running `/entitydata @e[type=Item,r=3]`. Look in the error message for the `Item:{}` tag, and edit your villager command accordingly.